# Share common configuration items among hydra config groups

Tags: yaml, fb-hydra

I have two sets of config groups, from which I need to select one config file each time.
the file structure looks like this:

```
conf
├── datasets
│   ├── A
│   │   ├── a1.yaml
│   │   └── a2.yaml
│   └── B
│       ├── b1.yaml
│       └── b2.yaml
└── config.yaml
```

I could choose dataset config with `dataset=A/a1` or `dataset=B/b1`, etc.

Now suppose each config file in A or B has many items in common(that's why they are grouped in two subfolders).

The question is:

How could I specify these **common items** in A and B, without having to specify them in each config file under these folders?

The resulting file structure may look like this:

```
conf
├── datasets
│   ├── A
│   │   ├── a_common.yaml  # common config items for a1 and a2
│   │   ├── a1.yaml
│   │   └── a2.yaml
│   └── B
│       ├── b_common.yaml  # common config items for b1 and b2
│       ├── b1.yaml
│       └── b2.yaml
└── config.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a defaults list in the a1/a2/b1/b2 files:

```yaml
# A/a1.yaml
defaults:
  - a_common

...  # a1 contents
```

References:

- The [tutorial on defaults lists](https://hydra.cc/docs/1.2/tutorials/basic/your_first_app/defaults/)
- The [reference page for defaults lists](https://hydra.cc/docs/1.2/advanced/defaults_list/)